# JAXB marshalling / unmarshalling NullpointerException dilemma

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using a `java.xml.bind`-annotated Bean to create an XML output format that **omits collections *if* they are empty**. For that purpose the respective Getter has to look like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "titles")
@XmlElement(name = "title")
public List<XmlTitle> getTitles() {
    if (titles.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return titles;
}
```

This works fine during marshaling. Sadly, I am getting a `NullpointerException` once I want to **unmarshal the very same XML file**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Lister.java:269)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.add(Scope.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ReceiverImpl.receive(ArrayERProperty.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.endElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:107)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:158)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:123)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:754)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:735)
```

This has to do with namely that Getter returning `null`. As some JAXB expert explains on the [Glassfish JAXB forum](https://java.net/projects/jaxb/lists/users/archive/2011-05/message/52):

> The JAXB unmarshaller does not expect setters for properties of type
>   List; it'll just use x.getSomeList().add( y ) to add another child.

How do I best solve this dilemma?

Comment: Keep the logic outside the bean?

Comment: Why return a `null`and not an empty list?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi If I return the empty list, I end up with unwanted empty tags in the XML output.

Comment: How does your xml and your jaxb annotated classes look like?

Answer (score 1):

As per exception JAXB does not allow lists to be `null` when marschalling. So instead of using the annotation `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "titles")` you could create a wrapper class which you use in the containing class to hold the list of `XmnlTitle`. If you look as `xjc` generated classes you will find that this is exactly how it handles wrapped list elements.

Also JAXB automatically omits elements which are `null`, this is how you managed to not unmarschal the list by returning `null` when `size() == 0`

Wrapper:

```
public class XmlTitleWrapper {
    private List<XmlTitle> title;

    public void setTitle(List<XmlTitle> title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    public List<XmlTitle> getTitle() {
        if(title == null) {
            title = new ArrayList<XmlTitle>();
        }
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "XmlTitleWrapper [title=" + title + "]";
    }
}
```

Container:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Container {

    private XmlTitleWrapper titles;

    @XmlElement(name = "titles")
    public XmlTitleWrapper getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

    public void setTitles(XmlTitleWrapper titles) {
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Container [titles=" + titles + "]";
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Container c1 = new Container();
List<XmlTitle> title = Arrays.asList(new XmlTitle("A"), new XmlTitle("B"));
XmlTitleWrapper wrapper = new XmlTitleWrapper();
wrapper.setTitle(title);
c1.setTitles(wrapper);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JaxbUtil.toXML(c1, writer);
System.out.printf("%s%n", String.valueOf(writer));
```

this will generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<container>
    <titles>
        <title>
            <value>A</value>
        </title>
        <title>
            <value>B</value>
        </title>
    </titles>
</container>
```

If you remove the line setting the wrapper

```
c1.setTitles(wrapper);
```

thus leaving it `null` in the container, then the output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<container/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a XmlAdapter in which you control marshalling and unmarshalling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it by implementing the callbacks defined by JAXB. Use unmarshaller callback, afterUnmarshal to clean up the list.

```
@XmlElement (name = "title")
List<XmlTitle> theTitles = new ArrayList<XmlTitle>();  
...
void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller aUnmarshaller, Object aParent)
{
    if (requiredBooks != null)
    {
        Iterator<XmlTitle> iterator = theTitles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            XmlTitle theTitle = iterator.next();
            if (null == theTitle)
            {                    
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```